# linking a Visual studio project to a library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mlpack

I built mlpack (an additional library for c++) using Visual Studio 2015. All the library files are inside the build folder

now when Iam trying to compile the following code in visual studio after adding the mlpack location in additional directories,as shown [added the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOK1p.png) i get error saying "cannot open include file 'mlpack/core.hpp':No such file or directory"

```html
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <mlpack/core.hpp>
    using namespace mlpack;
    int main()
    {
    }
```

even though core.hpp is there inside the included mlpack folder
[it is there!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkqHk.png)

how do i add this file and compile without errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check additional include directories in your project/C++ properties settings.
As you've used the <> directive your compiler is looking for project-level paths and I'm guessing you've not added one for the directory where the mlpack library is located.
Good luck!

Comment: How do I add that??

Comment: Right-click on project (not solution) and select Properties.
Navigate to Configuration Properties->C/C++->General.
On the RHS of the window locate the entry for 'Additional Include Directories'.
When you have a moment also to get familiar with the LHS "C/C++" and "Linker" configuration sections.  You'll be using those two quite a bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

You confused additional library directories from Linker tab with additional include directories (what is used for includes) from C/C++ tab. Additional library directories is for `.lib` files, not for `.h`/`.hpp`.

Also better use `#include "mlpack/core.hpp"` instead of `#include <mlpack/core.hpp>` for your own libraries.

Comment: #include "mlpack/core.hpp" works well  :) ... But it throws more errors because in all the files of mlpack <> is used instead of "" (there r about 550 more errors due to this). Is there any other way instead of replacing each  <> by "" ??